# Set image source to a URI

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

If i have a link to an image online and i want to set the image source to this uri, how should i do it best? The code i'm trying is shown below.
`<Image Name="Poster" Height="400" Width="250" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,8,0"/>`

`BitmapImage imgSource = new BitmapImage();

 imgSource.UriSource = new Uri(movie.B_Poster, UriKind.Relative);

 Poster.Source = imgSource;`

Also, if i want to cache this image to load it again how is this done?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the right way to do it. If you want to cache the image for later re-use, you could always download it in the Isolated Storage. Use a `WebClient` with `OpenReadAsync` - pass the image URI and store it locally.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("IMAGE_URL"));

void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("image.jpg", System.IO.FileMode.Create, file))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (e.Result.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
        {
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Reading it will be the other way around:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("image.jpg", System.IO.FileMode.Open, file))
{
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.SetSource(stream);

    image1.Source = image;
}
```

Comment: When i run this i get an exception saying:
A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute URI.

Comment: What URI are you passing and where exactly is the exception thrown?

Comment: This is the uri i'm passing:  
`http://www.foo-web.net/res2/Adele Blanc - Sec.foob`  
And the exception happens at this statement:  

`imgSource.UriSource = new Uri(movie.B_Poster, UriKind.Relative);`

Comment: Oh sorry i found the problem, the UriKind should be Absolute not Relative.
Thanks again Dennis :)

Comment: The URI you are passing is absolute - you should use `UriKind.Absolute`.

Comment: No actual reason to opening a fileStream to read it. The phone can access IsolatedStorage content directly using the isostore:// URI scheme. Also, `PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg` might be necessary as well with the current solution.

Comment: No need for `PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg` here. The solution works out of the box as it is. Also, `BitmapImage` doesn't exactly behave well with the `isostore` schema.

Answer (score 1):

You've done it correctly.

To cache an image, you would download it to your local file store with either a `WebClient` (easiest) or using the `WebRequest`-`WebResponse` mechanism. Then, next time you go to set the image location, check if it exists locally. If so, set it to the local file. If not, set it to the remote file and download.

PS. You'd need to keep track of these and delete old files, or you'll fill up the phone's memory very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are setting the image source in code-behind is absolutely fine. The other alternative, if you are using binding / MVVM is to convert your string URL to an image source using a converter:

```
public class StringToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    string url = value as string;
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    return new BitmapImage(uri);
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```