# How to set my downloaded image to my listbox UI object?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, iteration

I'm working in a Windows Phone 7 application that download several images at run time (meaning they are not added on my executable as resources).

For downloading the images I use the approach described on the next link: 
[Set image source to an uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940880/set-image-source-to-a-uri)
and it seems to be working fine.

I'm having a hard time trying to set my downloaded images to my list box which contains a custom control.

In my xaml page my lisbox looks like this:

```
  <ListBox x:Name="listBox_1" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
           <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                         <mylocal:customcontrol_A id="{Binding PId}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                          <toolkit:WrapPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"  />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  </ListBox>
```

My custom control contains an Image and several TextBlock's as follow:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="180" Width="470" Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="452*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="18*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Name="img_1" Source="{Binding PImage1, Converter={StaticResource requestConverter}}" />
    <TextBlock Name="txtB_0" Text="{Binding PName0}" Foreground="Black" />
    <TextBlock Name="txtB_1" Text="{Binding PName1}"  Foreground="Black" />
</Grid>
```

Im using the Converter to launch the webclient that will download the image.

Once my asynchronous request has completed, and I have my image stored in my IsolatedStorageFile area, I can build a BitMapImage on the callback of my MainPage, but I haven't found how to iterate through my listBox_1 in order to access my custom command Image to set the Source property as in the above link suggested.

I would like to do something equivalent to the next

```
 BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
 image.SetSource(stream);

 foreach (customcontrol_A bc in listBox_1.Items)
 {
      if (bc.id == id)
      {
            bc.img_1.Source = image;
            founded = true;
            break;
      }
 }
```

But the problem is that listBox_1.Items are instances of myBindingClassA, not of the actual GUI elements customcontrol_A.

I would really appreciate any suggestion on how can I get a reference to the Image GUI object so I can simply set the Source with a BitmapImage.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: One quick question before I answer, Why do you need to store it locally? Do you know for a fact the image will never change?

Comment: Hi Shawn, yes, it will not change, and I need it locally in case the app is used in an area without connection, also to do it only one time and save data consuming to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily put the lazy load logic within the viewmodel that holds your `PImage1` property. Your property would need to return an ImageSource.

```
private ImageSource _source;

public ImageSource PImage1
{
    get
    {
        if (_source == null)
        {
            using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (storage.FileExists("Image.jpg"))
                {
                    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                    bitmap.SetSource(storage.OpenFile("Image.jpg", FileMode.Open));
                    _source = bitmap;
                    return _source;
                }
            }

            LoadImage();
        }
        return _source;
    }
    set
    {
        _source = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("PImage1");
    }
}
```

Inside the LoadImage method, you'll make a request to get your image, save it to local storage, and then set the PImage1 property. Make sure to set the property on the UI thread

```
private void LoadImage()
{
    // make a request to get the image. 
    // Use your flavor of choice, WebRequest, HttpClient, WebClient

    Stream image = GetImageFromMyFavoriteHttp;
    using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (var file = storage.CreateFile("Image.jpg"))
        {
            image.CopyTo(file);
        }
    }
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(image);
        Image = bitmap;
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for your response, so, if I understand correctly the properties request from my binding class does no happen on the GUI thread, right? or in other words, this aint going to block the app until the image request download has completed, is this correct?

Comment: requesting the property value does happen on the UI thread, but the request to your [web] service does not (sort of). It will issue the request on the UI thread.